# Why I can not give the 'ln -s' command an operand through out the command sub $(ls ../*.txt)?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ln

```
ln -s $(ls ../*.txt)
```

When I do the command above it replay with an error message saying : "ln: target '../foo.txt' is not a directory".

foo.txt is the first file that ls command has found in the parent dir.

I am trying to make symbolic links for all the files in the parent directory which ends with ".txt".

Can you please explain why my command did not work ?

Comment: Your attempt to use `ls` in a command substitution is dangerously close to [Bash Pitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is #1...)

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: In the future, you can find this type of errors by yourself, when running the code with `set -x` being activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the directory name to put all the links into. If you want them put into the current directory, use `.`.

There's also no need to use `ls`, and you'll get the wrong results if any of the filenames contain whitespace or wildcard characters, because those will be processed in the `$(...)` output. Just use the wildcard directly.

```
ln -s ../*.txt .
```